# Why is TIdHTTP.Head() generating an 'HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable' exception?

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

I'm trying to use `TIdHTTP.Head('https://www.myurl.com/myfile.zip')`, just to get the file size before downloading it.

I get the file size so I can open multiple threads downloading parts of the file in parallel, so the download will be faster.

It was working OK until recently, when the `Head()` method started to raise this exception:

> Project myproject.exe raised exception class EIdHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable'.

My `TIdHTTP` is connected to a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`, with these `SSLOptions`:

```
Method = sslvSSLv23
SSLVersions = [sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]
```

What should I look for?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Request.Accept := 'application/zip' did the trick, thank you ! Please post as answer so i can accept.

Comment: I've posted an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `406 Not Acceptable` error comes from the HTTP server. It *usually*<sup>1</sup> means that the request has an `Accept` header specifying the type(s) of data the client is willing to receive, but the server is not able to send the requested resource in any of those types.

<sup>1</sup> Less likely, the error could also mean an intermediate firewall is blocking the request.

The default `TIdHTTP.Request.Accept` value is `'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'`. The `*/*` *should* include `.zip` files, but if you know that you are only interested in a `.zip` file and nothing else then you should set the `TIdHTTP.Request.Accept` property to `'application/zip'` instead.

---

On a side note: you should NOT be enabling `sslvSSLv2` and `sslvSSLv3` in the SSLIOHandler's `SSLVersions` property. They are old and deprecated, as they are no longer secure, nobody uses SSL v2.0 and v3.0 anymore.

Comment: Thank you for you valuable help over the years Remy, i really appreciate it. I'm your fan !